# Xampp local host not show even mysql and apache starts

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using XAMPP for Windows 5.6.14 .yesterday i installed XAMPP and configure Apache and MySQL ports  and connect to the local host.I was able to create databases also .But today I  when I try to connect to local host phpmyadmin 
after starting MySQL and Apache  it shows

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

How can I solve this??

Comment: Do you have green status indications for all your services, in particular MySQL and Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10?? If so, find your hosts file and uncomment the 127.0.0.1 line. If not, I'm not to sure. It's in Windows/system32/drivers/etc and edit with notepad after running it as an administrator.

Comment: No I am using  windows 8.1

Comment: Maybe look into it anyways. Also, try right clicking the xampp and running it as admin when you load it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your XAMPP installation directory e.g. C:\xampp
2. Open xampp_start.exe executable file
3. When process complete (Cursor stops blinking), close this window
4. Now open xampp-control.exe file
5. Now you will see all the controlls and module for XAMPP
6. Start Apache, MySQL and other Module if required
7. You will see the Sea green status message here if service successfully starts
8. Now open your localhost in browser

If you still not able to open localhost then try to change the http port e.g. 8080.
Change this line in apache config file:

- Listen 8080
- Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
- ServerName localhost:8080

Open localhost:
http://localhost:8080/

I hope it will work.